# TimePicker in a {minutes:seconds} format

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I need to implement a timepicker in a {minutes:seconds} format. 
Seems like neither the DatePicker nor the TimePicker allow for seconds..

So it leaves me wondering- is there a good custom control for minutes:seconds out there I could use? Would it be possible to adjust/morph TimePicker to my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mim/archive/2013/04/16/winrt-create-a-custom-itemspanel-for-an-itemscontrol.aspx 
^ supplies a code- I'm implementing it now- will update once I tinker with it a little.

Answer (score 0):

There is clearly such control used in pre-installed timer app:

[image]

Comment: hey Dave
where's that timer app installed?
how do I access it's code to get the control?

Comment: It's this app: https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9wzdncrfj3pr, Sadly I have no idea where to get the source.